# Why is my shell printing incorrectly after killing a process?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm doing background processing when the '&' is on the end. I think it's working correctly, but for some reason after doing any command after killing a process, "Ben$" is printing oddly, and I can't figure out why.

This is what it's printing:

```
Ben$ ls
Makefile  shell2  shell2.c  stableshell2.c
Ben$ sleep 20 &
Ben: started job 30892
Ben$ kill 30892
Ben$ ls
Ben$ Makefile  shell2  shell2.c  stableshell2.c
ls
Ben$ Makefile  shell2  shell2.c  stableshell2.c
```

Any ideas?

```
/*
  Shell 1
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  while (1) {
      char line[100];
      char *temp;
      char *split[15];
      int pid;
      bool background=false;

        printf("Ben$ ");

    //if cmd-d, exit shell
     if(!fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
      printf("\n");
      break;
   } 

      line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
      temp=strtok(line," ");


      if (strcmp(temp, "exit") == 0) {
        break;
      }
      else if (strcmp(temp, "cd") == 0) {
        char *arg = strtok(0, DELIMS);

        if (!arg) {
          fprintf(stderr, "cd missing argument.\n");
        }
        else {
          chdir(arg);
        }

      } else {
      int i=0;
      while(temp != NULL) {
        split[i]=temp;
        temp=strtok(NULL," ");
        i++;
      }
      split[i] = NULL;
      if(strcmp(split[i-1], "&")==0) {
        // printf("should do in background");
        split[i-1]='\0';
        background=true;
      }

      char *args[i];
      int j;
      for(j=0; j < i; j++){
        args[j]=split[j];
      }


        pid=fork();

        if(pid==0) {
        if(background) {

                  fclose(stdin);
                  fopen("/dev/null","r");
        }
        execvp(args[0], args);
        printf("This should not happen\n");
      }
      else {
        if(!background) {
          // printf("Not in background\n");
             wait(&pid);
        }
        else {
           printf("Ben: started job %d\n",pid);
        }
     }
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not "odd".

You're invoking processes asynchronously, so you get their output interleaved in your console.